# How to take the content of .txt url without using axios or fetch

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a link which is like https://sampleFile.txt,
I want to download this file with content in onClick method without using axios/fetch methods, because I am getting CORS issues, I have tried to achieve this by using javascript or jQuery in reactjs many ways, But i didn't get any solution.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: https://github.com/garmeeh/local-cors-proxy

Comment: If you are using some back-end API (spring, php, etc.), you could download and read it. CORS policies were made to increase security for external requests and assets.